# MySQL Selecting the latest payments from a table with a list of users with multiple payments

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table full of user payments. Each user can have multiple payments. I'm looking to select the latest payment for each user.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(MAX(p.date)), "%D %M %Y") as last_payment, p.user_id, p.amount, p.period, p.txn_id, u.name 
FROM payments as p
INNER JOIN users as u
ON u.id = p.user_id
GROUP BY p.user_id
ORDER BY p.date DESC
```

Now this seems to work fine, the `last_payment` field is indeed the date of the users latest payment, the only problem is that the other payment fields like `p.txn_id` and `p.amount` do not necessarily correspond to the same row as the users last payment, but from a previous payment.

How do I make sure that when i'm choosing the `MAX(p.date)` it's also choosing the other fields from that same row.

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [groupwise maximum](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html); the most common way is to join the payments table back to the grouped results:

```
SELECT   DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.date), '%D %M %Y') AS last_payment,
         p.user_id, p.amount, p.period, p.txn_id, u.name
FROM     payments AS p NATURAL JOIN (
           SELECT   user_id, MAX(date) date
           FROM     payments
           GROUP BY user_id
         ) t JOIN users AS u ON u.id = p.user_id
ORDER BY p.date DESC
```

Note that the only reason your original query worked at all (and didn't throw an error) is because of [MySQL's non-standard extensions to `GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-extensions.html):

> MySQL extends the use of `GROUP BY` so that the select list can refer to nonaggregated columns not named in the `GROUP BY` clause. This means that the preceding query is legal in MySQL. You can use this feature to get better performance by avoiding unnecessary column sorting and grouping. However, this is useful primarily when all values in each nonaggregated column not named in the `GROUP BY` are the same for each group. The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate.

Comment: Thank you! This appears to work just how I want it. The only issue is that the query takes 4.5s to complete, is there any way of speeding this up?

Comment: @Wasim: Does your `payments` table have an index on `(user_id, date)`?

Comment: Ah yes of course, I didn't have it for the date, now it's much faster. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT u.*
     , x.*
  FROM payments x
  JOIN (SELECT user_id,MAX(date) max_date FROM payments GROUP BY user_id) y
    ON y.user_id = x.user_id
   AND x.date = y.max_date
  JOIN users u
    ON u.id = x.user_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.date), "%D %M %Y") as last_payment
       , p.user_id, p.amount, p.period, p.txn_id, u.name 
FROM payments p, users u
WHERE u.id = p.user_id 
  and exists (SELECT max(p1.date) from payments p1 
               where p1.user_id = p.user_id 
              having max(p1.date)=p.date 
               group by p.user_id,  p1.date )
ORDER BY p.date DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I haven't tried this but is it not possible to acheive this using the `INNER JOINS`?

Comment: This statement doesn't work - `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group by p.user_id,  p1.date )
ORDER BY p.date DESC' at line 17`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(p.date, "%D %M %Y") as last_payment, p.user_id, p.amount, p.period, p.txn_id, u.name 
FROM payments as p where 
INNER JOIN users as u
ON u.id = p.user_id
GROUP BY p.user_id having FROM_UNIXTIME(p.date)=FROM_UNIXTIME(MAX(p.date))
ORDER BY p.date DESC
```

Comment: This does not work, this only works for rows where `p.date` happens to be the same as the row thats selected after the `GROUP BY` happens